# Equivalent to C++'s std::clog in Python?

Tags: python, c++, clog

This piece of C++ code will display a "loading text" on the Terminal as the main program renders an image. I know that it does it because of the *std::clog*. I've been searching, and I think that the *subprocess* module can help me with reproducing this on Python, but I have absolutely no idea on how to use it. How would you code this in Python?

```
   std::stringstream progress_stream;
   progress_stream << "\r  progress .........................: "
                    << std::fixed << std::setw( 6 )
                    << std::setprecision( 2 )
                    << 100.0 * y / ( buffer_.v_resolution_ - 1 )
                    << "%";

    std::clog << progress_stream.str();
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with using `print` and choosing `stderr`?

Comment: @chris This was what I needed, but I didn't know about it. It worked just as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent is `print(a_string_variable, file=sys.stderr)`.

Comment: I'll try it and give feedback! Thank you for now!

Comment: UPDATE: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!